# Carrierwave on Rails 5.1 uploader instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I followed the carrierwave instructions, I did the `rails generate uploader Attachment` but when I do

```
uploader = AttachmentUploader.new
uploader.store!(my_file)
```

it doesn't upload the my_file attachment. I dont want to store the my_file string in the database

Answer (score 0):

If we take a look at CarrierWave's documentation

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md#multiple-file-uploads

I will use Product as the model I want to add the pictures, as an example.
 Get the master branch Carrierwave and add it to your Gemfile:

```
  gem 'carrierwave', github:'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
```

Create a column in the intended model to host an array of images:

```
rails generate migration AddPicturesToProducts pictures:json
```

Run the migration

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Add pictures to model Product

```
app/models/product.rb

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  mount_uploaders :pictures, PictureUploader
end
```

Add pictures to strong params in ProductsController

```
app/controllers/products_controller.rb

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, pictures: [])
end
```

Allow your form to accept multiple pictures

```
app/views/products/new.html.erb

# notice 'html: { multipart: true }'
<%= form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  # notice 'multiple: true'
  <%= f.label :pictures %>
  <%= f.file_field :pictures, multiple: true, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png" %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

In your views, you can reference the images parsing the pictures array:

```
@product.pictures[1].url
```